# Image Swap by thumbnail hover?

Tags: jquery, css, image, hover

http://visually-minded.com/portfolio-project.php

On the above link when the user hovers over any thumbnail the main image will be swapped. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction for a tutorial for this?

Answer (score 3):

with html:

```
<img id="target" src="full_img_name1"/>
<a href="full_img_name1"><img src="thumb1"/></a>
<a href="full_img_name2"><img src="thumb2"/></a>
<a href="full_img_name3"><img src="thumb3"/></a>
```

and a script:

```
$("a img").hover(function(){
  var img = $(this).closest('a').attr('href');
  $('#target').show().attr('src',img);
},function(){
  $('#target').hide().attr('src','');
});
```

Comment: On a related topic... http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/news/2010/10/patent-troll-takes-over-the-web-can-it-be-stopped.ars

Answer (score 0):

Here it is used with on click.

http://monc.se/kitchen/80/lightweight-image-gallery-with-thumbnails

just over looked the code. But should be something like what you are searching

Comment: That example is perfect. Many Thanks SCBoy

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dead simple CSS-only implementation if you are not comfortable with javascript:

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/gallery4.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$(element).hover(
    function () { $(this).data('original', $(this).attr('src')).attr('src', newsrc),
    function () { $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('original')
);
```

I don't know how you define the new source for the image but this is pretty much the way to go. In addition you probably want to use each() on every image and inside define the 'newsrc'.

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery you can do this:

```
$(function() {
$('#myImage-hover').hover(function() {
    $('#myImage').attr("src","path-to-file/img.png");}, function() {
    $('#myImage').attr("src","path-to-file/img_2.png");

    });
 });
```

As exampled [here in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/UKXEy/).

Comment: could you expand upon this?  I have a similar issue but with different thumbs and corresponding images